# Compilation issue while upgrading from Grails 2.2.2 to 2.5.1

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am doing a migration from Grails 2.2.2 to Grails 2.5.1.While upgrading that i am facing compilation issue for

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder
```

class which is present inside

```
spring-security-core-1.2.7.3\src\groovy\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\springsecurity\ReflectionUtils.groovy
```

I am using spring-security-core 1.2.7.3 and spring security ldap 1.0.6 version inside my plugin dependency tag inside the buildConfig.groovy. I tried to update the version but i am not finding the right combination for both the jars.
Could someone help me to find the correct version of both the jars which is compatible with 2.5.1 Grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"` for the core plugin and `compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0.1"` for the LDAP plugin.

Your BuildConfig.groovy should look like this:

```
grails.servlet.version = '3.0'
grails.project.work.dir = 'target'
grails.project.target.level = 1.7
grails.project.source.level = 1.7

grails.project.dependency.resolver = 'maven'
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   inherits 'global'
   log 'warn'
   checksums true
   legacyResolve false

   repositories {
      inherits true
      mavenLocal()
      grailsCentral()
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      ...
   }

   plugins {
      compile ':spring-security-core:2.0.0'
      compile ':spring-security-ldap:2.0.1'
      // other plugins
   }
}
```

Comment: Failed again during compile time.This time with the error `- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0
- org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ldap:2.0.1`  .. Do i need to include any maven  repo url inside the repositories tag.

Comment: Delete your target directory to get rid of the old plugins first

Comment: Did not help.Just wanted to check  Do i need to include any maven repo url inside the repositories tag?

Comment: thanks for providing the correct plugin version.It helped.